# CUDA error at cuCtxCreate : unknown error

Tags: cycles-render-engine, error, linux

os : Pop!OS 
ver : Blender 2.81
device : nVidia GeForce GTX 1080ti

every time my computer falls asleep with blender open, when i try to get back to my work i get this error and blender can't find any CUDA devices when i try to turn it off and on again. this seems to be fixable only with a system reboot but i'm hoping there is a better way. Has anybody experienced this issue and has a way to fix it ?

some additional info - i had the same problem using older versions of Blender and this would also happen under ArchLinux

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before when rendering an animation.
The solution is to simply decrease the tile size under performance.
[image]

Comment: When rendering an animation your graphic card's memory is filled with data, so reducing the tile size reduces the memory load. I understand how it helps for rendering, but how does it effect the idle computer falling asleep?